# Detect hiDPI mode

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.8

Working with Qt 4.8.4 on OS X -- **Desktop Application development**. I need to be able to detect, at paint time, if I am on a hiDPI display ("retina") or not. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually I just created a small cocoa function to return this value for me. I use it to determine the time of paintEvent whether I should use hiDPI images. Works like charm on my MacBook Pro 15" Retina.

```
bool MYAppCocoaServices::isHiDPI(QWidget * widget)
{
    NSView* view = reinterpret_cast<NSView*>(widget->winId());
    CGFloat scaleFactor = 1.0;
    if ([[view window] respondsToSelector: @selector(backingScaleFactor)])
        scaleFactor = [[view window] backingScaleFactor];

    return (scaleFactor > 1.0);
}
```

I am building this .mm file conditionally on Mac only and call this static function from my c++ code on Mac.

Comment: Why the vote down? Qt 4.8 doesn't support Retina fully and I don't want to use modules I don't need just to ask this boolean question. It works nicely, so why vote it down?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `QScreen` for this in Qt 5, and in Qt 4 you can use the `QSystemDisplayInfo` class from Qt Mobility.

### For Qt 4

There is `QSystemDisplayInfo` - http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility/qsystemdisplayinfo.html

The relevant methods are `getDPIHeight` and `getDPIWidth`.

You could also use `QDesktopWidget`'s `physicalDpiX` and `physicalDpiY` methods.

### For Qt 5

Use `QScreen` - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qscreen.html#physicalDotsPerInch-prop

```
((QGuiApplication*)QCoreApplication::instance())
    ->primaryScreen()->physicalDotsPerInch()
```

There are also `physicalDotsPerInchX` and `physicalDotsPerInchY`.

Comment: QSystemDisplayInfo does not exist on any file on my disk. I am building a dekstop application, using the "regular" Qt 4.8.4.

Comment: @RM1970 It is part of Qt Mobility, which might not be in the package you downloaded. Try `QDesktopWidget` instead.

Comment: The method analogous to the accepted answer is `QScreen:: devicePixelRatio()`